# Query Assistance with Error - Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to do a cross join between two tables to ensure the values are allocated to each row, but I'm experiencing the resources exceeded error. I wanted to see if there may be something else I can try to be sure that the values are basically joined together like a cross join. The businesses table has about 400k records while the permissions table has about 750k records.

```
with SEG as (select
             concat(business,' Visitors') as segment
             from `business`
             group by 1),
                         
    PERM as (select
             user_id,
             email,
             client_id 
             from `permissions`
             group by 1,2,3)
                         
select distinct
PERM.user_id,
PERM.email,
PERM.client_id,
SEG.segment,
from SEG
cross join PERM
```

Comment: Side note, you don't have a column named `segment_name` in SEG. The query will fail on that.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just updated it.

Comment: You are legitimately wanting 300B row result set? Are you sure? This feels a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/438222).

Comment: If there's a way to trim it, that'd be great. But yeah, each segment should be allocated to each user and client ID. I didn't originally build the process, so hoping there's a way to fix what currently exists without having to re-invent the wheel...though honestly, seems like I should.

Comment: Since it's a cross join, and also sides of joins are already distinct, you don't need a distinct in the final query. You can try it by deleting distinct at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way you can see limited data so that it wont take time is by limit the number of rows. Use the below query for that

```
WITH SEG AS (
  SELECT CONCAT(business, ' Visitors') AS segment
  FROM business
  GROUP BY 1
),
PERM AS (
  SELECT user_id, email, client_id
  FROM permissions
  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
SELECT
  PERM.user_id,
  PERM.email,
  PERM.client_id,
  SEG.segment
FROM SEG
CROSS JOIN PERM
LIMIT 1000; -- Adjust the limit as per your requirement
```